# Visual Studio 2015 project authentication is wrong when using custom template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have created a custom ASP.NET MVC template in Visual Studio 2015 Pro that is supposed to use Windows authentication by default. I have noticed an odd behavior in that when a new project is created from this template, the project Properties Window shows that Windows Authentication is disabled and I get an "Access Denied" error if I try to run it. The original project has the proper option set in the Properties Window and the web.config file in the template does contain the proper authentication tag (shown below). If I go in and try to edit the project file in a text editor, there is no mention anywhere that Windows authentication is disabled. I have verified that this also happens in a base MVC project with nothing changed other than the Windows authentication setting and that it is happening on all of our computers that have VS.

Once the template is used, rebuilding the project does nothing. I can change the mode immediately to make it work, but even more strange is that if I close and reopen the project the setting will change to "Enabled" and it works fine. Neither of these solutions are acceptable as it may lead other developers on a wild goose chase that has a simple solution. Is there something that I need to change in the template itself for Visual Studio to recognize this or is this a bug? I've yet to find any other accounts of this.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <allow roles="MY_DOMAIN\Domain Users" />
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: Are you using IISExpress or Local IIS?

Comment: I am using IISExpress.